# Identify Permissions for Given User

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, permissions

I have looked at all the options in Central Admin. I need a way to search for effective permissions for a given user for all sites and lists. There is just a single Publishing site collection.

Is this possible via the Central Admin GUI (maybe I missed something)? Or is there a PowerShell way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no out of box way to get this via Central admin.
you have to use 3rd party tool or use powershell script.
I have this very good script(from technet gallery), which will find all SharePoint sites and lists where a particular user has access rights.
[SharePoint Permission Report: Check Access Rights for a Specific User](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Permission-2840f327)

Answer (score 2):

I built this PS script.  This may help.  It outputs to CSV.

```
function getUserGroups()
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") > $null
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
$websvcs = $farm.Services | where -FilterScript {$_.GetType() -eq     [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]}

foreach ($websvc in $websvcs)
{
    foreach ($webapp in $websvc.WebApplications)
    {
        #this will parse through all web applications
        foreach($site in $webapp.Sites)
        {
            #this will parse through all sites
            foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
            {       
                foreach($list in $web.lists)
                {
                    #this will parse through all lists within subweb
                    $unique = $list.hasuniqueroleassignments
                    if(($list.permissions -ne $null) -and ($unique -eq "True"))
                    {
                        foreach($listRoleAssignment in $list.RoleAssignments)
                        {                                       
                            foreach ($listRoleDef in $listRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                            {
                                $principal = $listRoleAssignment.Member
                                if ($principal.GetType() -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup])
                                {
                                    $data = @{
                                        "Site Collection" = $site.Url
                                        "Role" = $listRoleDef.Name 
                                        "Web Title" = "List or Library - " + $list.Title
                                        "URL" = $web.URL
                                        "Group Name" = $principal
                                        "Group Description" = $principal.Description
                                    }
                                    #save the data into new object
                                    New-Object PSObject -Property $data 
                                }
                                $unique = $null
                                $principal = $null
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }          
                foreach ($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments)
                {
                    #$roleGroup = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup]$principal
                    foreach($roleDef in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                    {
                        $principal = $roleAssignment.Member
                        if ($principal.GetType() -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup])
                        {
                            #gather data about each group
                            $data = @{
                                "Site Collection" = $site.Url
                                "Role" = $roleDef.Name
                                "Web Title" = $web.Title
                                "URL" = $web.URL
                                "Group Name" = $principal
                                "Group Description" = $principal.Description
                            }
                            #save the data into new object
                            New-Object PSObject -Property $data 
                        }
                        $pincipal = $null
                    }
                }
            }
            $web.Dispose()
        }
        $site.Dispose()
    }
}
}
function go()
{
write-host "Starting Operation"
getUserGroups | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Scripts\groups.csv
write-host "Operation Complete"
}
clear-host
go
```